# Custom UINavigationController Implementation

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, implementation

I've got a TabBarController in my app and in it I've got a few NavigationControllers. I've got all this stuff simply made in interface builder.
Now I want to implement my custom navigationcontroller so I created a class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end


@implementation DetailNavigationController

- (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"I work!");
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And in Interface builder I added this class as Custom Class to the navigation controller I want. Now when I start the app and select the tab with this navigation controller it works but the initWithRootController is not called. I guess it's completely ignoring the class and runs as default navigation controller.
Do I need to specify anything more in interface builder or do I need to specify this controller programatically somewhere in tabbar delegate?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating the navigation controller in interface builder, you will need to override `initWithCoder:`, not `initWithRootViewController:`. The xib contains an instantiated version of your object, with the root view controller already set.